# Having trouble getting oledbcommand to execute on a per row basis

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

Trying to get a gridview to check every row for a checkbox then add that record into a "cart" table if it is checked.  The logic is set to fire when a user clicks a button.  I know it probably isn't that efficient to open and close with every loop, but I can't think of another way to do it and still modify the parameters with every loop.

```
 protected void ShoppingCartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//set up connectionstring and oledbconnection
    OleDbConnection myconn = new OleDbConnection();
        myconn.ConnectionString =     "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data     Source=|DataDirectory|\\ProjectDatabase.accdb";

    string UserID = Session["UserID"].ToString();
//retrieves the UserID for the session.  If no userid is present, the     button won't be visible to the user(in page load)

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
//checks row by row
    {
        string unpredictable = "";
//checks where a checkbox is checked
        CheckBox chkCtrl1 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkCtrl");
             if (chkCtrl1.Checked)
          {  //if it is, grabs the gameid and puts it into the string
                    unpredictable = row.Cells[1].Text;
//declared the oledbcommand here
              OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
//insert based on username and gameid
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Cart ([Username],[GameID]) values (?,?)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", UserID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameID", unpredictable);
//opens the connection and closes it with each loop   
myconn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
myconn.Close();

           }




    }
```

Comment: I should have elaborated.  It won't save to the table

Comment: And the exception is? :) I think the mistake here is the parameter names in the INSERT statement. Can you try with this: "insert into Cart ([Username],[GameID]) values (@Username, @GameID)";

Comment: For some reason it's not detecting the box being checked.

Comment: I can't see the grid view code here, you can debug the code and in the Quick Watch window list (CheckBox)row.Controls. This will give you the list of child controls of the row. From that, you can find what you are looking for (the check box), after that, you can search for that control with it's Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- remove the back-slashes from your connection string after |DataDirectory|. also add: providerName="System.Data.OleDb" (maybe not required).
- your OleDbCommand doesn't know the connection string. move the sql into a string:

`string sql = "insert into Cart ([Username],[GameID]) values (?,?)";`

then create the command:

`OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, myconn);`